# curl fails sending file towards a FTPS

Tags: networking, ftp, curl, upload

Trying to send "test_file" to FTPS server.

```
curl -v -k --ftp-ssl --tlsv1 --ftp-ssl-reqd --ftp-pasv --key key_nopass.pem --cert client.pem --user 'user:pass' --upload-file test_file ftp://Ftps.example.com:21/
```

**It connects, but after, is failing. Here's some output:**

```
> * Connected to EXAMPLE.COM_IP_ADDRESS (IP_ADDRESS) port 21 (#0)
> < 220 Microsoft FTP Service
> > AUTH SSL
> < 234 AUTH command ok. Expecting TLS Negotiation.
> * successfully set certificate verify locations:
> USER username
< 331 Password required for username.
> PASS thepassword
< 230 User logged in.
> PBSZ 0
< 200 PBSZ command successful.
> PROT P
< 200 PROT command successful.
> PWD
< 257 "/" is current directory.
* Entry path is '/'
> EPSV
* Connect data stream passively
< 229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||5013|)
*   Trying example.com.ip.addess
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:09 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:03:09 --:--:--     0* Connection timed out
* couldn't connect to host
* got positive EPSV response, but can't connect. Disabling EPSV
> PASV
* response reading failed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:03:09 --:--:--     0
* Closing connection #0
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
} [data not shown]
curl: (56) response reading failed
```

Seems like after the "Connected to EXAMPLE.COM_IP_ADDRESS (IP_ADDRESS) )" and "logged in", it says "**couldn't connect to host**", even though, in a few lines above seems to be connected "

**UPDATE**:
Running the same command with the "--disable-epsv" argument, seems it's trying to open data channel ports as well:

```
* Connect data stream passively
< 227 Entering Passive Mode (A,B,C,D,19,179).
```

Where A,B,C,D is the server's IP and I think the other ones: 19,179 are the ports. Right? PS: the last number (179) is being incremented by 1 at every time I run the command.

Comment: Remember that FTP uses a control channel and datachannel. Is the data channel (a random, high numbered port) allowed from client to server?

Comment: Vidarlo I think you're right. Please see my updated question. 19 seems to be the port, but I'm not sure for the other one (179), which is incremented by 1 every time I try to connect. I think that's also a port, right?

Comment: It appears that the remote host is not set up correctly for accepting PASV connections. If possible, do not use FTP. It's an ancient, broken, protocol.

Comment: I use curl for client, and the customer's FTP server has a ftpS (microsoft ftp secure)